# Is there an opens source library to generate public/private keys in angular/ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, end-to-end-encryption

I am not sure this is a SO question but I have been searching for a library similar to keypair or libsignal that allows you to generate public/private keypairs in angular and ionic. I am trying to create an end-to-end encrypted application using angular and ionic on the client side. I have tried Keypair but it comes with a polyfill warning and has not been updated for years. I have also looked at libsignal client for typescript but it looks like a node implementation. Maybe there's another solution to what I am trying to do using angular/ionic. I just want to create a public/private keypair at login or on request...send my public key to the server where others can grab it encrypt a small text and ..save the encrypt text on the server where I can grab in and decrypt in on my client?  any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, one of the flags in SO is precisely *"Asking for recommendations about [...] software libraries"*, so yeah, sorry but this is not an SO question.

Comment: @S. Dre ....I suspected so.....I will ask a specific question on one of the libs I am trying.

Comment: Check [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I see a lot more "which X would you..." type of questions there

Answer (score -1):

You can use [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge)

```
rsa_generateKeyPair() {
    let pair = Forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(2048, 0x10001)
    return {
      private: Forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(pair.privateKey),
      public: Forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(pair.publicKey),
    }
}
rsa_decrypt(key:string, data64:string) {
    let privateKey = Forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(key) ;
    let data = Forge.util.decode64(data64) ;
    return privateKey.decrypt(data) ;
}
rsa_crypt(key:string, data:string) {
    let pubKey = Forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(key);
    let data64 = Forge.util.encode64(pubKey.encrypt(data)) ;
    return data64 ;
}
```

Comment: I tried to install this before...but it gave some problems....I will get back to it and post the actual issues.